# How to write function in R which gives same output as in the following stored procedure?

Tags: r, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server and I am re writing it in R. I am unable to get same output in R as from the stored procedure.

```sql
ALTERProc [dbo].[UPD_CREDIT]          
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @ssispath VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @ssispath = 'H:\RMS PKG\UPD_CREDIT.dtsx'

    SELECT @cmd = 'dtexec /F "'+ @ssispath+'"'
    SELECT @cmd = @cmd

    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

    if exists(select top 2 *, task = (select TaskName from Table1 A         
where A.id = B.id and A.taskid = B.taskid)
              from Table2 B 
              where id = 5        
                and taskstatus = 'N'orderby taskrunID desc)
    begin
        RAISERROR('THERE IS AN ERROR IN EXECUTIoN ', 16, 1);
    end
```

And my R function is

```r
UPD_CREDIT <- function(){

  Table1 <- dbSendQuery(conn, 'Select * from Table1') 
  Table2 <- dbSendQuery(conn, 'Select * from Table2')
  func1 <- function(Table1, Table2){
  Table2 <- Table2 %>% filter(id = 5, taskstatus == 'N') %>% arrange(desc(taskrunID))
  task <- merge(x = Table1,y = Table2 ,by =c("id","taskid"))
  if (nrow(task) >2) {
    res = TRUE }
    res = FALSE
    return(res) }
  res <- func1(Table1, Table2)
  if(res){print('THERE IS AN ERROR IN EXECUTIoN')}   
}
```

I am unable to get this part , how to execute these in R

```
declare @cmdvarchar(1000)
    declare @ssispathvarchar(1000)
    set @ssispath='H:\RMS PKG\UPD_CREDIT.dtsx'

    select @cmd='dtexec /F "'+ @ssispath+'"'
    select @cmd= @cmd
    execmaster..xp_cmdshell@cmd
```

Comment: Have you tested the R code in R? It doesn't look vectorized to me.  Of course I know noting about SQL Server so the requirements may be completely different than I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, those lines are passing values into a command line shell call to the [SSIS `dtexec` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017) which R can similarly run with `system()`.

This assumes R is running in same environment (to access the H drive object) with same user or privilege to call stored procedure. Possibly this utility updates *Table1* and *Table2* of same connected database. Also, you can run the `merge` directly in database with a `JOIN` and avoid importing both tables client-side.

```r
# COMMAND LINE CALL
ssispath <- 'H:\\RMS PKG\\UPD_CREDIT.dtsx'
cmd <- paste0('dtexec /F "', @ssispath, '"')    
system(cmd)

UPD_CREDIT <- function() {
    # SQL SERVER QUERY
    task <- dbSendQuery(conn, paste("SELECT *", 
                                    "FROM Table1 t1",
                                    "INNER JOIN Table2 t2",
                                    "  ON  t1.id = t2.id AND t1.taskid = t2.taskid",  
                                    "  AND t2.id = 5 AND t2.taskstatus = 'N'")
                       )

    if(nrow(task) > 2) print("THERE IS AN ERROR IN EXECUTION")
}
```